# How can I apply a function that I created to each successive row of a column in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a 4 rows in a column that I want to iterate over and apply a function to.
The df is a column and the values for instance are:
a
b
c
d

I want to apply the function in this way:
function(a,b)
function(a,c)
function(a,d)
function(b,c)
function(c,d)

How can I do this in python?
I've tried using df.apply(lambda column: compare_score, axis=0)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKJXa.jpg)

Comment: You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to generate the pairs. Something like `[function(*pair) for pair in itertools.combinations(df, 2)]`